# Human Face Recognition Variable (google-cloud-vision)

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am working on implementing human face recognition into an iOS application. I receive back many tags like 'glasses' or 'smiling' but don't see an actual variable that tells me it is a human face (and with what degree of confidence).

What variable am I missing and how can we use that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may not using the correct **feature type** as it is seems that you are getting labels instead of facial attributes.

I recommend you to check the [Detecting Faces](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces) and [Face Detection Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/face-tutorial) documentation where you can find detailed information and some useful examples that you can use as a reference to know more about the process of [detecting faces](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/other-features#faces) with **Vision API**.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow few steps to detect faces from an image.

1. Create your URLRequest

   ```
   func createRequest() -> URLRequest? {
       // Create your request URL
       if let url =  URL(string: "YOUR_API_KEY") {
           var request = URLRequest(url: url)
           request.httpMethod = "POST"
           request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
           request.addValue(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-  Ios-Bundle-Identifier")
           let jsonRequest = [
               "requests": [
                   "features": [
                       [
                           "type": "FACE_DETECTION",
                           "maxResults": 10 //change as per your requirement
                       ]
                   ]
               ]
           ]
           let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonRequest)
           request.httpBody = jsonData
           return request
       }
       return nil
   }
   ```
2. Run the request in background thread

   ```
   let task: URLSessionDataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
       guard let data = data, error == nil else {
           print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
           return
       }
       print(data)// Analyze with this data
   }
   task.resume()
   ```
3. Analyze data (on main thread if you want to update any UI component)

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            do {
                guard let json =
                    try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else { return }
                guard let responses = json["responses"] as? NSArray else { return }
                if responses.count > 0 {
                    guard let response = responses.firstObject as? [String: Any] else { return }
                    guard let faceAnnotations = response["faceAnnotations"] as? NSArray else {
                        print(false, "No face detected, please try another photo.")
                        return
                    }
                    if faceAnnotations.count > 0 {
                        print("Face successfully detected: \(faceAnnotations.count)")
                    }  else {
                        print("No face detected, please try another photo.")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error while face detection process, please try again.")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error while face detection process, please try again.")
            }            
        })
```